# Why was this upvoted answer deleted once, and deleted again when reposted?

Tags: support, deleted-answers, specific-answer

[Why does my JavaScript code receive a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error, while Postman does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-code-receive-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-i/69032516?noredirect=1#comment122629489_69032516)

I posted an answer to this question that multiple readers upvoted.

> [image]

After noticing it had been deleted without explanation I reposted my original answer.

> [image]

A couple of upvotes were received.  Again without explanation the answer was deleted with the mod leaving this comment:

> If you have an objection to something a moderator does, use a flag or post on meta. Please don't simply recreate the deleted content. Continuing to do so will result in a suspension. –
> meagar

I thought SO was a community where great answers were upvoted and future people with the same issue could benefit from the pain and suffering of others who had already solved the problem.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46099357/4826457) was your original answer? From the comments you do know it doesn't address the question

Comment: The comments under the first answer indicate that you are not really answering the question. I can't judge that since I'm no domain expert, but not answering the question is a reason to get an answer deleted.

Comment: The answer did address the question and received multiple upvotes.

Comment: The re-posted answer was also upvoted so users clearly found it helpful.

Comment: Well did you read the mod note on the question: "_This question is **not** about how to fix a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'..." error. It's about why they happen._"

Comment: And my answer explained WHY IT WAS HAPPENING TO ME.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat: To be fair, the mod message wasn't there when op added their first answer.

Comment: It does not answer the question about difference between browser and postman (or other REST clients) at all

Comment: [Image of the first answer by OP there](https://i.imgur.com/VLLYJin.png) (for the <10k users). Second answer is already in the question.

Comment: I can see this pointless.

Comment: @NoRefundsNoReturns: Your answer doesn't at all talk about why the request works through postman, but not through other methods.

Comment: 70 answers, of which 66 are deleted? What a magnet that question is.

Comment: "and received multiple upvotes" - [so did this steaming pile of off-topic garbage](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55884514/6296561). The upvotes don't prove that the answer has value

Comment: Request through a browser were KO'ed by a request from POSTMAN.  Maybe that wasn't obvious to anyone EXCEPT people who were having the problem.  "Upvotes don't prove value" if that was true SO wouldn't be so popular.

I'm done here.  I followed the direction from the moderator and all I got was shouted down.  What a waste of time.

Comment: *"... all I got was shouted down. What a waste of time."* - You blissfully ignored everyone else's feedback and didn't get shouted at, so thanks for wasting every who took parts time.

Comment: @yivi to be fair all the deletions were unilateral from the same mod so not sure that one counts. A couple of those deletions there seem highly questionable TBH (though I haven't seen the one OP is complaining about)

Comment: @TylerH question shows "Viewed 5.1m times" - this looks like fairly solid justification for a moderator to perform [Atwood's cleanup](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/103069/165773)

Comment: The answer is offtopic, the error can be caused for a number of reasons, so definitely you will get upvotes when talking about one of them, but it is offtopic, look even at the mod note "This question is not about how to fix a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'..." error. It's about why they happen."

Comment: You're more than welcome to include how to fix a problem in a question like this– _but_ you must also address and answer the _actual question_. Yes, usefulness is really important to Stack Overflow, no questing about that– but you still have to address the OP question. It's just how we run things around here.

Comment: I mean... many of the answers that remain also don't answer the question, they give ways of solving various things that could be making CORS requests not function. (Granted, they also get to the point far quicker and have a far easier to understand format than the answer in question here)

Comment: @gnat Not sure which point you're responding to; I'm not arguing against deleting answers in general when there are many of them that more or less repeat the same information.

Comment: @KevinB Indeed, by meagar's apparent metrics for deletion, at least two of the remaining answers should be deleted, too: #2 and #6 by vote count currently. Didn't look closely at answers 3, 4, or 5.

Comment: I personally don't agree with narrowing this question down to just why postman works when the browser doesn't. That's not useful at all and is not what people are looking for. If that makes it too broad, we have a close reason for that.

Comment: @TylerH I am arguing against your point that deletions were questionable - in this specific case moderator acted following the way how site creater was supposed them to

Comment: @gnat I said only some of them were, not all of them.

Comment: Looks like you have a good answer to a question, just not the question in, er... question. Could be time for a new question with a self-answer.

Comment: An answer (or question) having "value" doesn't make it on topic or acceptable here.

Comment: Value is determined by a fair market.  If I happen to go to store A and find an unexpected gem, I don't tell the owner of store A that Store B is where people look for the gem.  I thank the owner of store A.  The english language has a word for that - serendipity defined as `the occurrence and development of events by chance in a happy or beneficial way.`  I used to think of SO as a cornucopia of serendipity.

Comment: 500+ upvoting a question asking how to bake a pie doesn't mean it's on topic to ask about baking a pie here.

Comment: If it's the number 1 result in google, maybe it should be.  Anyway ... I'm out.  Enjoy the pie and the fish.

Answer (score 14):

First of all, by reposting the answer after it got deleted by a moderator you acted very disrespectfully. Don't work around moderator actions just because you disagree with them. If you continue doing this, it will lead to an official warning or even account suspension.

The reason why your answer got deleted was that it was not an answer to this question. It was more of a comment along the lines "we had a problem unrelated to your question and we did this". This comment might have been helpful, but was completely orthogonal to the topic.

The question is "[Why does my JavaScript code receive a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error, while Postman does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-code-receive-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-i)" How does your deleted post answer this question? It doesn't and it deserved to be deleted. Your answer doesn't even mention Postman, let alone explain the difference in behaviour.

I'm sorry that your contribution to the site has been deleted, but we must keep Stack Overflow clean. Huge threads with a lot of answers do not help people solve their issues quickly. If you believe that your problem is unique and you really want to share the resolution, please create a self-answered question. In the question explain what the issue was, and in the answer provide the solution with an explanation. This way people searching for that same issue will be able to quickly locate the appropriate solution.

Comment: Anyone who actually had the problem you emphasized here, like me, and used PostMan, like me where it worked but didn't from the site, like me, would probably love to hear that making the PostMan request is the root cause of the problem, like it was for me. None of the fine folks who have issues with me seem to have ever used Akamai or a similar CDN that was misconfigured causing monetary and reputational losses because of it. Too bad StackOverflow won't be there to help the next poor soul who, like I had too, will wish there had been a hint that PostMan and the CDN conspired to cause issues.

Comment: +1 for explaining us all the opportunity to post self-answered questions. However, quite too strong the wording stating that answerer was disrespectful (when maybe he didn't knew that this was a wrong thing to do). Probably I am biased because I just can't understand why moderators intervened and insisted that readers must *only* answer why Postman software behaves such or such way instead of also trying to solve that issue, too. It's entirely useless just to diagnose a problem if you can't repair it as well. Probably 5 mill people really needed to see a solution not just why it does happen.